# Probability distribution for score of dice game?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In the game, ten $D_{20}$ (twenty-faced) dice are rolled. If any of the dice are $1$, you remove one of the "$1$", and get a point. Of the remaining dice, if any are $\le 2$, you remove one of them and get a point. This continues for dice $\le 3, \le 4,\dots ,\le 10$ whereupon the score is the total of the points, so the minimum and maximum score for a round of this example are zero and ten respectively.

I'm trying to derive the distribution of scores for the general case of $N$ dice all with $F\ge N$ faces being rolled and scored as outlined above for dice $\le 1, \le 2, \dots ,\le N$.

For simpler cases, I've just enumerated and counted, for larger cases I've summed the PDF for the various cases over a multinomial distribution, but these become intractable/impractical for larger cases.

Is there a more direct way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: I at first misunderstood the method of scoring, so the function described here does not directly produce the desired result. It has, however, proved useful in creating an algorithm that will provide the desired result.*

I simulated the game to predict the probabilities for each score, then started with the obvious $P(0) = \left(\frac{19}{20}\right)^{10}$ and attempted to find $P(1)$ close to the predicted value. That was easy enough, we need $1\times d_i\le1$ and $9\times d_i>2$, so $$P(1)=\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)\left(\frac{18}{20}\right)^9{10 \choose 1}$$

After that, it gets a little tricky. For $P(2)$ we need $2\times d_i\le2$ and $8\times d_i>3$. That would give us $P(2)=\left(\frac{2}{20}\right)^2\left(\frac{17}{20}\right)^8{10 \choose 2}$, but we haven't dealt with the fact that one of the two must be $1$. Our options for $2\times d_i\le2$ are $(1,1)$ $(1,2)$ $(2,1)$ and $(2,2)$. Three of those four meet our requirements, so $$P(2)=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{2}{20}\right)^2\left(\frac{17}{20}\right)^8{10 \choose 2}$$

Continuing in this manner, we find $$P(3)=\left(\frac{16}{27}\right)\left(\frac{3}{20}\right)^3\left(\frac{16}{20}\right)^7{10 \choose 3}$$

Notice that $\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3^1}{2^2}$ and $\frac{16}{27}=\frac{4^2}{3^3}$ has a nice pattern, so we'll use $\frac{5^3}{4^4}$ to find $$P(4)=\left(\frac{5^3}{4^4}\right)\left(\frac{4}{20}\right)^4\left(\frac{15}{20}\right)^6{10 \choose 4}$$

We now have $4^4$ in both numerator and denominator, so we'll cancel those out. Also, $5^3 = (4+1)^{(4-1)}$ and that is helpful too. $$P(4)=\left(\frac{(4+1)^{(4-1)}}{20^4}\right)\left(\frac{15}{20}\right)^6{10 \choose 4}$$

Now we have a function of $S$, $N$, and $F$, and that is $$\bbox[border:2px solid green]{P(S)=\left(\frac{(S+1)^{(S-1)}}{F^S}\right)\left(\frac{F-S-1}{F}\right)^{N-S}{N \choose S}}$$
Double-check to verify: $P(0)=\left(\frac{1^{-1}}{F^0}\right)\left(\frac{F-1}{F}\right)^N{N \choose 0}=\left(\frac{F-1}{F}\right)^N$

Having used a modified version of this function to create an algorithm to calculated the number of permutations that produce each possible score, I now have the full results for $10\times D_{20}$ as shown in this table:
$$\begin{array}{crr} 
\text{Score} & \text{Number of Permutations} & \text{% of Total}\\
\hline
0 & 10,000,000,000 & 0.098 \\
1 & 105,937,424,601 & 1.035 \\
2 & 494,615,754,903 & 4.830 \\
3 & 1,336,197,364,620 & 13.049 \\
4 & 2,304,026,349,312 & 22.500 \\
5 & 2,635,684,516,614 & 25.739 \\
6 & 2,009,802,747,654 & 19.627 \\
7 & 995,634,522,252 & 9.723 \\
8 & 299,197,160,760 & 2.922 \\
9 & 46,546,211,593 & 0.455 \\
10 & 2,357,947,691 & 0.023 \\
\hline
\text{Total} & 10,240,000,000,000 & 100.000
\end{array}$$

Comment: Hi, appreciate the work, but it seems to get different numbers. For example, the case of 4 dice with 6 faces has probabilities of 1/81, 161/1296, 487/1296, 169/432, 125/1296 for zero to 5 successes respectively. $P(S)$ returns very different values.

Nonetheless, I think this is on the way to the right approach, I'll tinker with it. 

Thanks again.

Comment: @rasher I misunderstood the scoring. I thought that if you couldn't take a die at any point, then you were done. I'll work it over again tomorrow.

Comment: @rasher: Am I missing something, why isn't $P(0) = (5/6)^4$

Comment: @trueblueanil You made the same assumption that I did. The probabilities given in rasher's comment indicate that getting a point for removing a die $\le2$ is _not_ contingent on removing a die $\le1$. In the case of $4\times D_6$, $P(0)=(2/6)^4=1/81$ because at least one point will be scored when any die is $\le4$

Comment: And then, how is P(1) = 161/1296 ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Figuring that out can be a bit, um... dicey. We can have one die $\lt4$ and three dice $\gt4$ (e.g. $2565$) or all four dice $\gt3$ with at least one die $=4$ (e.g. $4456$). So $P(1)={4 \choose 1}\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^3+\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^4-\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^4=\frac{96+81-16}{6^4}=\frac{161}{1296}$

Comment: @Logophobic - You have it right. I'm beginning to think there may not be a simple, consistent form for this, and that one must build the various cases individually, but I'm still tinkering with your idea...

Comment: @rasher I have an algorithm (on paper) that will provide a complete solution. It may take me a few more days to finish, but I'll get code for you.

Comment: @Logophobic - Don't spend too much effort on my part - as I said, I'm doing it algorithmically. I'm sure the latter can be done more optimally, I posted here to see if any combinatorics experts had one of those "...well, of course, it's just this..." moments.

In any case, still tinkering with your OP idea, though it does seem there may not be a simple consistent expression so far.

Look forward to your results should you choose to pursue them.

Comment: @rasher I used to do this kind of coding as a hobby, though I don't have the resources that I used to have, so this is more for myself than it is for you. The code is Excel VBA, because I am most familiar with Visual Basic 6, but is not ready to be shared. If you like, I can post it as-is (uncommented), or I could attempt to write C code. For now, have a look at the output.

Comment: @rasher I have successfully translated my code to C. If you would like to see it, let me know where I can post it. I think it best to find an appropriate forum to allow for discussion.

Comment: @Logophobic - Google docs is pretty convenient, or http://codepad.org/ , or git, whatever works for you. We can open a chat room here to discuss. I look forward to seeing it, I'm sure it's more efficient than what I'm doing (TBH, I've not spent any time thinking optimization).

Comment: @rasher Code upload as [text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByFbErSheBzFNkczMWg3d1p0bWc/view?usp=sharing) on Google Drive

Comment: @Logophobic: Roger that, I will grab it this weekend and take a gander, will report back and/or open a chat...

Comment: Pretty clean, faster than what I was doing. Accepted, and thanks for the effort.